# Evaluation of TensorFlow and Random Forest Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to classify scan data with the help of TensorFlow. There are four classes. I have modified a csv file with the measured values so that I know which points belong to the classes.

Then I adopted the example (https://medium.com/@dineshmadhup_75545/comparison-of-tensorflow-and-random-forest-model-with-python-92a475f84faa) with modifications.

Since the probability is very high, I would like to check whether the correct class is estimated when entered manually. However, the target class should not be known.

```
Classification Report: 

          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.96      1.00      0.98        97
       1       1.00      0.96      0.98        68
       3       1.00      0.99      0.99        75

    accuracy                           0.98       240
   macro avg       0.99      0.98      0.98       240
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98       240


Confusion Matrix: 

[[97  0  0]
 [ 3 65  0]
 [ 1  0 74]]
```

A measuring point consists of only one X and one Z value, which is a float.
I created three measuring points manually by executing the following code.

```
point0 = {
"x": -15.35,
"z": 18.3458
  }

point1 = {
"x": -2.8,
"z": 9.408
  }

point3 = {
"x": 8.65,
"z": 14.3632
  }

dataframe0 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [point0.get("x", "")], 'z': [point0.get("z", "")]}
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [point1.get("x", "")], 'z': [point1.get("z", "")]}
dataframe3 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [point3.get("x", "")], 'z': [point3.get("z", "")]}
```

Afterwards I would like to have the class predicted e.g. at point0 class 0.

```
i0 = standardScaling(dataframe0)
pred0 = rf_model.predict(i0)
pred0
```

On all three points I get this result, which should not be the case:

```
array([1])
```

So I looked at `i0`. This one always is:

```
    x   z
0 0.0 0.0
```

If I use a csv list during training, these values are very small but never zero. Can anyone tell me how I can check a single measurement point correctly?

Comment: What is your question? What have you done so far?

Comment: I have executed the example exactly like this. If I check manually for the predicted class I always get 1 out. But I do not know why.